# Kelly's Criterion loss threshold

Tags: pr.probability

Let,

$0<q<1$

$b>0$

With equation,

$(1+xb)^q(1-x)^{1-q}=1$

$0<x<1$

Is there a closed-form solution for $x$, given that $q(1+b)>1$? Note that the latter condition guarantees exactly one solution, and without it there may be no solution.

Alternatively, can we at least prove that $x<2((q(1+b)-1)/b)$

This equation comes up in the analysis of the Kelly Criterion, where $x$ would be the threshold fraction above which betting is asymptotically nonprofitable.

Comment: Questions that begin with "say we have" or "so we have" have a very short half life on MO.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? There is almost certainly not a closed form solution...

Comment: Yes, i was looking for a closed-form solution, or some interesting approximation.

Comment: Also asked at math.SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2244777/kelly-criterion-threshold

Answer (score 3):

For an "interesting approximation" I would suggest running Newton's method (by hand) from the initial point $x=q,$ for one or two steps. Otherwise, here is a plot of the $x$ as a function of $b, q.$ Somewhat surprisingly, it looks convex (in your region $q(1+b) > 1)$! This should be provable.

[image]